# GroupBy on nested Enumerable

Tags: c#, linq

I am struggling to use `GroupBy` when grouping by a nested property of an object.

The data structure is like so:

```
public class Activity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Business> Businesses { get; set; }
}

public class Business
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And I have an Activities list (`IEnumerable<Activity>`) like so:

> - Activity 1
>
>   - Business A
>   - Business B
> - Activity 2
>
>   - Business B
> - Activity 3
>
>   - Business A

I want to end up with the grouping of activities under their respective businesses:

> - Business A
>
>   - Activity 1
>   - Activity 3
> - Business B
>
>   - Activity 1
>   - Activity 2

I've tried various combinations of `GroupBy` and `SelectMany`/`Select` but can't seem to get the groupings correctly mapped out.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following query:

```cs
var query =
    from a in Activities
    from b in a.Businesses
    group new { a, b } by b.Id into g
    select new 
    {
        Business = g.Select(x => x.b).First(),
        Activities = g.Select(x => x.a).ToList()
    };

var result = query.ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

It gets all unique businesses, and then creates groups from them with all the acitivities that contain this business:

```
var result = activities
    .SelectMany(a => a.Businesses)
    .DistinctBy(b => b.Id)
    .GroupBy(
        b => b,
        b => activities.Where(a => a.Businesses.Any(ab => ab.Id == b.Id)));
```

Note: I'm also assuming that the `Id` is the property by which it should group.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```cs
var businesses = activities
    //flatten the structure for every business
    //for every entry create a new object that contains the activity and business
    .SelectMany(x => x.Businesses, (activity, business) => new { activity, business })
    //group by the business id and for each id select all activities
    .GroupBy(x => x.business.Id, x => x.activity)
    //materialize the enumerable (not required)
    .ToList();
```